# Understanding Memory leaks for Context and ContextWrapper

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have a class which has a static variable which holds `Context` reference.

> `public static Context context;`
>
> Android studio gives a warning saying that **static references to the
>   Context class leads to memory leaks**

If I remove the `static` keyword, it does not give any warning.

Similar scenario with `ContextWrapper` class as well.

My understanding is, if we hold a reference to the classes which are related to `Context` will lead to memory leak. But, Why Android studio does not give any warning for non-static `Context` references?

I have seen some code examples where they have extended the `ContextWrapper` class. Whenever they needed the `Context`, they are accessing through the class which was extended `ContextWrapper'. **Will this approach does not lead to Memory leak?**

Also, Will memory leaks happens for non-static `Context` references at runtime? Did I understand it in wrong way? Am I missing something here?

Can anyone give explanation for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/641473 by [Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23072/uri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First things first, let's know about memory leaks and why it happens exactly**

Memory leaks occur if there is any data in memory which can't be garbage collected ,Having said that, `static` variables can't be garbage collected as they stays live in memory throughout the Application life where as `non-static` variables can be garbage collected once it's enclosing parent is no longer referenced, keeping this in mind we'll see example to explain your question.

**Consider class A with a static and non static Variable**

```
Class A{
   private static Context iCanNeverBeDestroyed; 
     // Scope -> Application life, so memory leak can occur
   private Context iCanBeDestroyedWithA;  
      // Scope -> A
   private static int itWontMatterWhetherImDestroyedOrNot; 
     //Even though the scope is Application, due to low memory usage , memory leak is negligible in this case
}
```

Leakage is calculated based on scope of variable and size in memory together, high memory and greater scope has greater chances of leak, example like Context,Bitmap etc

Comment: You mean If class `A` lives till the Application destroys, then this will lead to memory leak?

Comment: It doesn't work that way,  Memory which is in use won't be garbage collected obviously and it's not considered as memory leak, if you are using only `A` throughout Application that won't be a leak, if you switched to `B` and `A` is not collected then it would be memory leak.