# Share class is not cleaned when activity and service detroyed

Tags: java, android, service, singleton

1. I have one app use an foreground service, this service can close by user. I created one class contains some state varialbles that common referrence by activity and service. when I closed service first and, close app after, this class was cleaned but when I closed app first then close service, this class was not detroyed(I known this due I have one count var in this class and its not cleared when retart app). So will my app leak mem? and good way to solve it.

this is my class

```
public class serviceState {
    public static boolean isMyServiceRunning = false;
    public static boolean sysConnectState = false;
    public static boolean sysAuth = false;
    public static int count = 0;
}
```

2. Second question. On this service I used a ringtone manager to play a voice warning. it's worked ok but  only play about 270 times, on the next time, the sound was changed to default notification tone but unkown reason why. this is my ringtone on servied:

```
placed onCreate
RINGTONE_VIBRATE = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), "sound file path");

use:
if(!RINGTONE_VIBRATE.isPlaying())
   RINGTONE_VIBRATE.play();
```

Thanks everyone so much!
Sorry for my english

I want solving my issue

Comment: 1. I would direct you to this accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641462/can-using-too-many-static-variables-cause-a-memory-leak-in-java in short I doubt it given what fields you are using currently, if you start adding in other stuff this could change.
2. Not enough information to determine what is the problem you need to post more code involving the ringtone issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @avalerio,
for 1, as your link, someone said that it is permanent class (even if activity and service closed). when I tried close all and leave it about several hours, this class reset. so is GC will remove it when need?

about 2. I mean when I used ringtoneManager to play a sound file in resource , it only play about 250 times and auto changing to sys default sound. my initialize follow:

```
public class bleAPI extends Service{
  private Ringtone RINGTONE_VIBRATE;

  protected void onCreate(){ 
    RINGTONE_VIBRATE = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), "sound file path");
  }

  ...

  //register eventbus to receive data
  @Subscribe   
  public void OnCustomEvent(rxData data) {  
    if(data.getState(),equal("vibrate")){
        sendNotification(); //notification set mute, only vibrate
        if(!RINGTONE_VIBRATE.isPlaying()) RINGTONE_VIBRATE.play(); // only play around 250 times and auto                                       switch to system default sound  
    }
  }
}
```